# Migrate OAuth2/OpenID configuration back from Azure to onsite ADFS 4 (windows server 2022 / 2019 / 2016)

Tags: active-directory, adfs, azure-web-apps, oauth, openid

Desperate noob here... my question is somewhat related to "[Migrating from Azure AD SSO authentication to ADFS](https://serverfault.com/questions/1076055/migrating-from-azure-ad-sso-authentication-to-adfs)" and "[Installing ADFS in Azure for Internal-Only access](https://serverfault.com/questions/927533/installing-adfs-in-azure-for-internal-only-access)" though these look overkill to me -- what we deal with is just one on-prem cloud Java web app and one need for Azure AD -> on-Prem AD transition, no federation / SSO / MFA, and no connection to external networks. We are at freedom to rinse-wipe-repeat (no data yet), incl. whole DC / AD setup with any Windows Server version. There is no even a need to be future-proof, as this is a short-term setup to try-before-you-buy a narrow-niche above mentioned app from an independent dev that uses Azure AD as authentication provider.

What we are NOT at freedom to, is "use Azure AD as an authentication provider". Just, no. Non-negotiable. The dev cannot help, they just used the most straightforward approach (like samples from [Microsoft Learning course,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/azure-java-app-enable-authentication-authorization/) and Swagger framework), but they assert they didn't intend to specifically lock down their product to Microsoft, didn't hardcode or tweak any OAuth/OpenID parameters that the app uses.

So we first deployed this app for a test drive "as designed" (and must destroy it a.s.a.p.), just to make sure all parts work together and installation process is followed correctly. Yes, it all works with Azure. But we need it to work on local AD / FS. I couldn't find anything that would simulate Azure authentication for fully and permanently disconnected environment. **strong text**Please suggest if one exists, otherwise Windows Server AD / FS seems the most viable option.

I think it must be possible to mimic Azure AD for scenario as simple as ours, as all OAuth/OpenID part of our setup is a manual process -- creating accounts, registering enterprise web application in Azure, configuring the java web app before deployment... it's just the things are named differently, scopes/claims/rights/etc, but the core technology is the same, it's all about templates/conventions... right?

And so I was tasked to implement what I believe is possible.
Now, the more I search/read, the more I see how-to's and FAQ's pointing to the opposite direction, from on-prem to cloud, but not other way around.

Am I dead wrong?
If yes, is there are bulletproof technical reason?
Or I just failed to find the right guidance?

I think all I need is either a reference table like "what means what where, Entra ID vs. 2022 AD FS", or some how-to for creating an analog of Azure's enterprise application in Windows Server AD FS 4 properly. Maybe someone came across a pre-Azure variation of a course on Microsoft Learning that I referred above, that teaches how to "properly" configure that Windows AD as a web app authentication provider?

By "properly" I mean the provider will not not break the flow when extra parameters (scopes, tokens, etc) are sent (or not sent) by a simplistic Swagger-based web app, and it won't send back any such parameters that could confuse the app.
In other words, can there be a generic approach for a use case like this?

For a baseline -- this is what we put in configuration file when re-deploying the app:

```
Registration ID ( api://{unique GUID-formatted value of Azure Single Page application} )
Client ID, may be also called "App ID" 
unique GUID-formatted value is the same as above
Metadata ( https://login.microsoftonline.com/{free Azure tenancy ID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration )
Authentication URL ( https://login.microsoftonline.com/{free Azure tenancy ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize )
Token URL ( https://login.microsoftonline.com/{free Azure tenancy ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token )
Authentication Authority ( https://login.microsoftonline.com/{free Azure tenancy ID}/v2.0/ )
```

A guidance like "Value A comes from field B in dialogue titled C, part pf workflow D" would be useful.
Or maybe someone saw a .ps1 to generate such configuration?
(again, this is nowhere close to prod, just a standalone isolated/offline env)

F1, F1 please!... gulp.. gulp... gurgle.... (bubbles, silence)